# How to make homing missiles(auto aim target)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I have a 2d game, and i want a missile to aim a target, but firstly i want to set to its trajectory some coll stuff lake a barrel roll.
I can't find (except for unity assets, i don't want to pay) how to make it, i mean both how to aim and how to set trajectory.
Even just aim help will be OK,
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you want for the turret to aim at the target, just do transform.LookAt(Target.position). You can use steering behaviors to home the missiles. Basically it will calibrate to the desired velocity needed to reach the target.
Here's an example:

```
//First we get the direction we need to travel in
Vector2 direction = (Target.position - transform.position).normalized;

//Multiply it by the maximum speed we're trying to reach
Vector2 desiredVelocity = direction * MaxSpeed;

//Subtract the current velocity. This is the calibration force
Vector2 steeringForce = desiredVelocity - rigidbody2D.Velocity;

//Apply the steering. The less the mass, the more effective the steering
rigidbody2D.ApplyForce(steering);
```

The barrel roll can be done separately from steering/homing. Just rotate on the Z axis. If you're talking about spinning in a circle... that's a bit more involved. You might want to just skip that or hardcode it with an animation.

Comment: He said 2d. Use `Vector2` and `rigidbody2d`.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. Changed the code and added some explanation.

Comment: :-)​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​